# Windows 8 App updates

Tags: windows-8

I want to publish an update for an app that is already in the Windows Store. When I create the new version, is it necessary to delete the old package, or the new one must be addeed to the list?

Comment: I don't know if you are suppose to delete the old ones or not, but I did.  I just did this yesterday morning. I deleted the old packages and then uploaded the new ones in their place. The new version passed certification and was put into the store this morning.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing. My problem is to know whether, in this way, the new version is recognized by the Store app as an update .

Comment: Did you create a new release in the dashboard? I should mention that I specifically created a new release and made all of my changes for that specific release. After my app was put into the store, the dashboard only shows the new release (v2); the old release (v1) is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one release of an app in the store at any one time.  Which means that once a new release in certified, it effectively overwrites the old one.  That doesn't necessarily relate directly to the packages, as you can create a new release with the same packages if you so wish (you do have to change something though, otherwise it won't let you resubmit).

Comment: This is clear, but my question is: when I create a new release, if it includes a new package, must I remove the old package before adding the new one, or must I add the new one, without deleting the old one?

Comment: It replaces the old package with the new, so deleting the old one is unnecessary.